# Axios request to yahoo weather API failing

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors, vuejs2, axios

I am working on a vuejs component that makes an ajax GET request to the Yahoo weather API using axios. I am receiving a CORS error in that the preflight check doesn't pass access control check.

However, I can make a request to the same endpoint using jqueries ajax method with no issues and the expected data is returned from the service. Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Here is the code from my vue component:

```
<template>
    <div class="tile" id="time-weather">
        <div class="date" v-text='this.date'></div>
        <div class="time" v-text='this.time'></div>
        <div class="temperature" v-text="this.temp"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import moment from 'moment';

    export default {
        created() {
            this.refreshTime();
            setInterval(this.refreshTime, 1000);

            this.fetchWeather();
        },
        data() {
            return {
                date: '',
                time: '',
                temp: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            refreshTime() {
                this.date = moment().format('ddd DD/MM');
                this.time = moment().format('HH:mm:ss');
            },
            fetchWeather() {
                const endpoint = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select item.condition from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text='Sunderland') and u='c'&format=json";
                const yapi = axios.create({
                    url: endpoint,
                    method: 'get',
                    withCredentials: false
                });

                const response = yapi.request();
                console.log(response);
            } 

        }
    }
</script>
```

The exact error message I am getting in the console is:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20item.condition%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text=%27Sunderland%27)%20and%20u=%27c%27&format=json.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://dashboard.dev' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

As I mentioned, if I make the request using `jQuery.ajax();` to the same endpoint, the request is sent with no issues.

There is probably something blatant that I am missing, but I cant seem to resolve this issue.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Are you sure? Given endpoint returns 404. Just checked it with cURL.

Comment: @jimmyweb Edited the link to https, my bad. Still getting the same result.

Comment: See the answer just now added. You can go into the Network pane in your browser devtools and reload the document and then examinine there the preflight OPTIONS request the browser is sending. You should check the request headers for that—in particular the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` request header the browser’s sending. That’ll contain the names of any custom request headers the axios request is trying to add to the request (and that are causing the preflight to fail). Maybe use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45849535/edit to edit/update the question and paste in those response headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From just the current details in the question, there’s no way to tell for certain why your browser’s making the [CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests)—but one thing that can be determined is that the reason it’s failing is because that `https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql` endpoint doesn’t send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header in `OPTIONS` responses.

You can confirm that using `curl` by doing this:

```
curl -X OPTIONS -i \
   -H 'http://dashboard.dev/' \
  'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20item.condition%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text=%27Sunderland%27)%20and%20u=%27c%27&format=json'

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 23 Aug 2017 22:12:40 GMT
Age: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Via: http/1.1 a44.ue.sg3.yahoo.net (ApacheTrafficServer [c sSf ])
Server: ATS
```

> I am working on a vuejs component that makes an ajax GET request to the Yahoo weather API using axios. I am receiving a CORS error in that the preflight check… if I make the request using `jQuery.ajax()` to the same endpoint, the request is sent with no issues.

That indicates `jQuery.ajax()` isn’t making the request in a way that triggers a preflight, but the axios request is. Almost certainly, the axios request is adding one or more custom request headers—I’m guessing probably the `X-Requested-With` header＊—which `jQuery.ajax()` isn’t.

*＊ **Update:** It turns out in this case the header that was getting added is `X-CSRF-TOKEN`.*

To tell for certain exactly what’s going on, examine the `OPTIONS` request the browser’s sending—in particular the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` request header in that `OPTIONS` request. That’ll contain the names of any custom request headers the axios request is trying to add to the request.

You can view the headers and other details of the `OPTIONS` request by going into the Network pane in your browser devtools and reloading and then examining the `OPTIONS` request there.

---

Anyway, there is a way you can get a request to that endpoint to work as expected regardless. You can make your request through a CORS proxy, by changing your frontend code to have this:

```
const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
const endpoint = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select item.condition from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text='Sunderland') and u='c'&format=json";
const yapi = axios.create({
    url: proxyurl + endpoint,
    method: 'get',
    withCredentials: false
});
```

That’ll send the requests through https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com—both the browser’s preflight `OPTIONS` request and your `GET` request. And the backend there forwards the request to that `https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql` endpoint and receives the response.

The backend there then adds the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the response—and in the case of the `OPTIONS`, also the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` response headers—and then passes that back to your requesting frontend code.

The browser will then allow your frontend code to access the response, because that response with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header is what the browser sees.

You can also easily set up your own CORS proxy using https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The reason it was failing was that in the Laravel bootstrap.js file, axios adds a X-CSRF-TOKEN header to the request. Once I removed that, the request was sent and the data was returned as expected. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: OK yeah that makes sense, because adding an  X-CSRF-TOKEN header to the request will trigger the browser to do an OPTIONS preflight. Cheers and glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting a response, but I need to use `https`, not `http` - this is true both with axios and JQuery.

Run the snippet below or this **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/ayKPwP)** to see the response:

```js
axios.get(
    "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select item.condition from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text='Sunderland') and u='c'&format=json"
  )
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.12.0/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Dan. It works if I run the code snippet on it's own, I also tried that earlier. Whenever I try to use it in a vuejs component as part of a Laravel app, it doesn't. Not entirely sure why!

Comment: Interesting. [This link](https://codepen.io/robinhuy/pen/VWLBYa/) is an interesting example of someone using axios on the yahoo weather api with vuejs. This person is also using the get and then methods for the ajax response. Hopefully this might help :) –